# Saving video with EMGU

Tags: c#, image-processing, video-capture, video-processing, emgucv

I can only save 1 frame of a video with my current code. but I need to save the video for a longer period of time. Can some one help me with this?

```
 public void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           frame = _capture.QueryFrame();
           imageBox1.Image = frame;
           VideoW = new VideoWriter(@"temp.avi", 
                                   CvInvoke.CV_FOURCC('M', 'P', '4', '2'), 
                                   (Convert.ToInt32(upDownFPS.Value)), 
                                   frame.Width, 
                                   frame.Height, 
                                   true);
           VideoW.WriteFrame(frame);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a problem with your code as far as I can see, that is process frame is attached to the `application.idle` event.

So when ever the application is idle this function is called and a frame is grabbed from the video source.

Now if we consider your `ProcessFrame` Function ,it just reinitializes the `VideoWriter` and writes a frame(current frame) in the video and that is why you only get a single frame in the output video.

So ideally your `ProcessFrame` should look something like this

```
public void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           frame = _capture.QueryFrame();
           imageBox1.Image = frame;

           VideoW.WriteFrame(frame);
    }
```

and the initialization of the `VideoW` variable ie, this underlying code.

```
VideoW = new VideoWriter(@"temp.avi", 
                                   CvInvoke.CV_FOURCC('M', 'P', '4', '2'), 
                                   (Convert.ToInt32(upDownFPS.Value)), 
                                   frame.Width, 
                                   frame.Height, 
                                   true);
```

It should be placed outside ideally in the `constructor` or where you have initilized other variables(`_capture` variables etc.)

check [this tutorial](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php?title=Video_Files)  for more about reading and writing video files in Emgucv.

Hoping  this helps.

Comment: Thanks! It sure did help me get a rough idea of how to format the codes =D